# RSpec: How to write correct association in test for fixing error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new in programming and try to write test but have an error:

staff:

```
belongs_to :contact
belongs_to :account
```

account:

```
has_many :staff
```

contact

```
has_many :staff
```

i try to write

```
subject(:service) { SomeService.instance }
let(:room) { create(:chat) }
let(:account) { create(:account) }
let(:contact) { create(:contact) }
let(:consultant) { create(:staff, account: account).contact} 
# or i try to write something like this 
let(:consultant) { create(:staff, account_id: account.id, contact_id: contact.id)}

   context  do
      subject { service.call(account: account, consultant: consultant)}

      it { is_expected.to respond_to(:call).with_keywords(:account, :consultant)}
   end
```

Error:

```
consultant = account.staff.find_by!(contact_id: consultant.id)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: 
Couldn't find Staff with [WHERE "staff"."account_id" = $1 AND "staff"."contact_id" = $2]
```

i think that i don't understand something fundamental. Please may you give me a few advices?

Comment: Sorry, think i fix this: let(:consultant) { create(:staff, account: room.account).contact}

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FactoryBot or FactoryGirl for your fixtures? I struggled with those when I was writing tests, because the documentation for RSpec is not the best. I'd suggest you use hard written fixtures, like the ones that Rails creates for you in `spec/fixtures`, then as you learn how the test database works you can migrate back to FB/FG. This really helped me understand what was going on.

Put the fixtures in files like `spec/fixtures/accounts.yml` and `spec/fixtures/contacts/yml`. Then in the spec, if you add the fixtures they will be loaded into the test database and you can use them as variables in your spec like so:

```
RSpec.describe "Some test" do
  fixtures :accounts
  fixtures :contacts

  context "test something" do
    let(:account_one) {accounts(:one)}
    let(:contact_one) {contacts(:one)}

    it "works" do
      # call variables like --> account_one
      ...
    end
  end
end
```